# scroll in usercontrol

Tags: c#, .net

In windows forms
I want to activate scroll to my usercontrol,
i activated autoscroll,
but the horizontal scroll is not appearing.

i have kept my control n tablelayout panel..

Help me for the horizontal scroll..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoScroll means that the scrollbar(s) will appear when some content sticks out of the Client Area. When you use a TableLayout (with Docking = Fill) then the AutoScroll does not kick in.

Turn of Docking for the TableLayout and set its Width/Height larger than the Form. You will see AutoScroll in the Designer.

Comment: Thanks henk:) but my code deals with someother problm i think lets c